# Work out person age in months sql

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Using the below as a basis how would i work out a person age in months i not to sure how to go about changing this so the months is cacualated instead of years

```
          IF cast(datepart(m, GETDATE()) as int) > cast(datepart(m,@in_DOB) as int)
    SET @age = cast(datediff(yyyy,@in_DOB,GETDATE()) as int)
      else
    IF cast(datepart(m,GETDATE()) as int) = cast(datepart(m,@in_DOB) as int)

    IF datepart(d,GETDATE()) >= datepart(d,@in_DOB)

    SET @age = cast(datediff(yyyy,@in_DOB,GETDATE()) as int)

    ELSE

    SET @age = cast(datediff(yyyy,@in_DOB,GETDATE()) as int) -1

    ELSE

    SET @age = cast(datediff(yyyy,@in_DOB,GETDATE()) as int) - 1

    RETURN @age
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its my birthday today :)  and I am `SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '13 Nov 1963', GetDate())` months old.  Whoops, too many beers already.

**Update**

```
DECLARE @birthdate datetime
DECLARE @months INT
SELECT @birthdate =  '13 Nov 1963'

SELECT @months = DATEDIFF(MONTH, @birthdate, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN DAY(@birthdate) > DAY( GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

SELECT  @months
```

Comment: But on the 1st of November, this query would give the same result as it does today, and as it will on the 30th.

Comment: Yes you are right.  Note to self stay off SO on your birthday, you give incorrect answers!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a mouthful, but we get the crude estimate just using [`DATEDIFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)<sup>1</sup> - and then we adjust it if it's wrong:

```
select @age = DATEDIFF(month,@in_DOB,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) -
    CASE WHEN DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,@in_DOB,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),@in_DOB)
              > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

<sup>1</sup> It's crude because `DATEDIFF` tells you the number of *transitions* that have occurred between two dates, rather than what some people might intuit. This means that the difference in months between 30th September and 1st October is 1, per this function.

So it can end up reporting a value 1 higher than the intuitive "difference in months" between two dates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to always save UTC date in db. will save you a lot of trouble.

```
select DATEDIFF(second,@in_DOB,GETUTCDATE())/(30.5*24*60*60.0) --days 30.5 avg of 30 and 31
```